# Redirect url if it contains #NOTECHWORKING

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I have searched for this for about a week now and still cant find an answer to my question so I'm finally braking down and asking here! What I am trying to accomplish is to redirect a URL ONLY if it contains #NOTECHWORKING at the end. Notice the #. I've tried simple redirects but nothing is working with the # included.

This is what I have tried with no success:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} #NOTECHWORKING  
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/chatclosed.html [L]
```

This:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} #NOTECHWORKING 
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/chatclosed.html [L]
```

And Also:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} #NOTECHWORKING 
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/chatclosed.html [L]
```

If this needs to be done in Javascript, I would have no clue how to accomplish this!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using JavaScript. to apply the command by using back/next buttons:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    var h=window.location.hash;
    if(h.substr(1) == 'NOTECHWORKING') window.location.replace("http://www.mydomain.com/chatclosed.html");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do not usually send #fragments to the server so your Rewrite conditions will never get triggered

You can accomplish a similar effect with Javascript by checking the value of the window.location.hash property

```
if(window.location.hash == "#NOTECHWORKING") {
    window.location.href = '/newurl.html';
}
```

This will however only work in browsers, so search engines will not be able to follow your redirect.

Comment: Search engines will ignore anything after the #, so they won't index them.